# ASP.NET Razor Pages - Client-Side Validation

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-webpages, razor

In ASP.NET web pages (or Razor pages), the new framework using the Razor view engine, is client-side validation supported, or is validation strictly server-side out of the box.  Of course there are other frameworks to handle that, but i'm speaking strictly of what's in the framework.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment, the out-of-the-box validation is server-side only. We're investigating client-side validation for future versions, but there's nothing to announce right now.